# Why does Daredevil's cowl have eyeholes?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, costume, daredevil-tv

In the final episodes of Daredevil 2015, he acquires his 'official' character suit. In the previous episodes he wore a scarf fashioned into a mask that covered the top part of his face.

Daredevil's 'official' cowl contains what appear to be two eye holes. What purpose can these serve?

Comment: Wouldn't he tip people off that he's blind if they *didn't* contain eyeholes?

Comment: @Walt - I think that's exactly the reason.

Comment: Because the actor isn't blind...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An eyeless mask might tip villains off that Daredevil is blind. This has at least 2 negative outcomes:

- It alerts them to certain physical vulnerablities that they can now exploit;
- They now know he's a young, built blind man, which might narrow the choices down and jeopardize his secret identity.

It actually makes you wonder why he *didn't* have eyeholes until now. Stan Lee [reportedly commented](http://captaincomics.ning.com/forum/topics/daredevil-questions-aka-i-was-wondering-20) on the subject with the same reasoning:

> When they made [The Trial of the Incredible Hulk TV movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trial_of_the_Incredible_Hulk), with Rex Smith as DD, [Stan Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee) saw that the mask had no eyeholes and asked why. They said that it was because he was blind. Yeah, said Stan, but no one was supposed to know that!

Comment: But on the other hand the idea that this ass-kicking super guy is actually blind is so outrageous that I would rather think he just looks through the cloth of his cowl or that his eyeholes are just not recognizable than the incredibly rare chance I have been beaten up by a blind man. But ok, if Stan Lee says it, it seems a reasonable thought.

Comment: The man who makes Fisk's knife proof suits, who is convinced to make Daredevils costumes has no idea Daredevil is blind, so he would naturally make eye-holes. Daredevil, when telling him what he wanted wouldn't add "oh btw make eye-holes so it isnt obvious im blind" because he doesn't need too. The costume maker would do that anyway.

Answer (score 12):

Also, a more obvious answer is that the guy who made him the red costume didn't know he was blind, so assuming he could see, he made him a costume with eye holes.